# capture delimited phrase with awk then remove strings

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with this content:

```
wewe-wev123-12343s
dsf-sdfs-1238674d
xcc-asdasd-234351g
dfd-sdfs-sdfssdf-2324g
dfgeg-dfgfg-dfsdf-2344G
```

my desired output is:

```
wewe-wev123-12343
dsf-sdfs-1238674
xcc-asdasd-234351
dfd-sdfs-sdfssdf-2324
dfgeg-dfgfg-dfsdf-2344
```

I want just remove strings at the last delimited part at the end.

What I tried is:

```
awk -F- '{print $3}' input.txt
```

How can I tell it to remove strings after digits at the end of lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the strings from the end, `sed` is a good tool:

```
$ sed -r 's/[^0-9]+$//' input.txt
wewe-wev123-12343
dsf-sdfs-1238674
xcc-asdasd-234351
dfd-sdfs-sdfssdf-2324
dfgeg-dfgfg-dfsdf-2344
```

The `-r` option to `sed` is just for convenience: it enables the use of extended regex syntax so we don't need so many backslashes.  The regex `[^0-9]+$` matches any non-numbers at the end of the line.  The substitution `s/[^0-9]+$//` removes all such non-numbers at the end of the line.

If the goal is to print the number in the third field, as in the first version of the question, then:

```
$ awk -F- '{sub("[a-z]+", "", $3); print $3}' input.txt
12343
1238674
234351
```

**Another variation:**  What if, as per @BMW's comment, the third field has no numbers but we still want to preserve the field markers and the first two fields in the output?  In this case, we would want to stop the letter-removal at the field marker.  To achieve this behavior, we only need add a single character addition to the `sed` command:

```
sed -r 's/[^-0-9]+$//' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much/// I updated the question..plz have a look

Comment: @ John, if the last column has no number, it will empty that whole line.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ cat file | cut -d- -f3 | grep -Eo '^[0-9]+'
12343
1238674
234351
```

We use `cut` because that's simpler than `awk`. And we use `grep` because that's simpler than `sed`.

- The `cut` command does the same as your `awk` command.
- `grep -E` means extended regexps, `-o` means only print the matching part. We match for 1 or more numbers at the start of the line, so any non-number is ignored (and not printed).

**Edit**

Your new output is different, we now just need `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/[a-zA-Z]+$//' file
wewe-wev123-12343
dsf-sdfs-1238674
xcc-asdasd-234351
dfd-sdfs-sdfssdf-2324
dfgeg-dfgfg-dfsdf-2344
```

- `-E` for extended regexp
- `s/` for substitute command
- `[a-zA-Z]+` to match these characters one or more times
- `$` to anchor the pattern to the end of the line
- `//` to replace with nothing

Comment: Thanks ..now how can I print this pattern `wewe-wev123-12343`..I mean I want remove all strings after all numbers

Comment: @MortezaLSC That will output `12343`, which is what you want?

Comment: Thank you very much/// I updated the question..plz have a look

Comment: @MortezaLSC Right. Updated answer.

Comment: Very good...But there is also some lines that chars at the end of line is not removed yet...

Comment: You should not post example using `cat`.  Most program can read files directly: `cut -d- -f3 file`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bash.

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ ([a-zA-Z])$ ]] && echo ${line%${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}
done < file
```

or

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ (^[a-zA-Z|-]+[0-9]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Both this `awk` should do:

```
awk '{sub(/[[:alpha:]]$/,"")}8' file
```

```
awk '{sub(/[^0-9]$/,"")}8' file
```

Comment: pardon, could you possibly explain them?

Comment: Number 1. Replace last character if its any alphabetic characters with nothing "". Number 2: Replace last character if its not numerical with nothing ""

Comment: Thanks but I mean what is `$/` and `8` exactly? Thank you

Comment: `$` is end of line, so last character before end of line. `/` is part of regex `/regex/`.  Any number for `awk` as command like `1` or `8` is always true, except `0`.  This will do default action.  so `8` = `1 {print}` = `1 {print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

using gnu grep

```
grep -Po '.*(?=[^0-9]+$)' file
```